# Не подставляется переменная в шаблоне jinja

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Загрузил первый раз через GitHub Pages "прототип" сайта. Сделал, как указано в инструкции. Сайт загружается ([enzo1987pavel.github.io/Classificator/](https://enzo1987pavel.github.io/Classificator/)), проблем не возникло.
Только вот для каждой страницы параметр "title" не выводит, а показывает только текст.
Делаю на Flask'е с шаблонами Jinja2.

Вот код из файла `main.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def main_page():
    return render_template("https://enzo1987pavel.github.io/Classificator/index.html", name="index", title="Главная")


@app.route("/about")
def about_page():
    return render_template("https://enzo1987pavel.github.io/Classificator/about.html", name="about", title="О сайте")


@app.route("/application")
def about_app_page():
    return render_template("https://enzo1987pavel.github.io/Classificator/application.html", name="application", title="О приложении")


@app.errorhandler(404)  # Форма для вывода ошибка при неправильном URL-адресе, если страница не будет найдена
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template("https://enzo1987pavel.github.io/Classificator/error_404.html", e=e), 404


@app.errorhandler(500)  # Форма при проблемах с сервером, внутренней ошибке в программе
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template("https://enzo1987pavel.github.io/Classificator/error_500.html", e=e), 500


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

В `render_template` загружаю нужные *.html-файлы и в параметрах данной функции не срабатывает параметр "title".

Вот один кусок кода из `index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Классификатор</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://enzo1987pavel.github.io/Classificator/css/style.css" type="text/css"/>

<!--icon -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/media/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/media/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/media/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/media/site.webmanifest">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/media/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
<!--icon -->
</head>

<body>
    <div class="text-align: center">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="col00" colspan="3" height="40"><a href={{ url_for("main_page") }}>{{ title }}</a></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="col0" colspan="3" height="60">Программа для классификации месторождений нефти и газа</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="col1">
                <div class="TextInColumn">Колонка 1-1</div><br>
                <div><a href={{ url_for("about_app_page") }}>{{ title }}</a></div>
            </td>
```

Как исправить? Помогите.

Comment: `<a href={{ url_for("about_app_page") }}>`  -> `<a href="{{ url_for('about_app_page') }}">`

Comment: @strawdog, а как с параметром "title" быть? так же отображается в виде текста...

Comment: ну вы везде проверьте у себя, где вы криво ссылки прописали. и исправьте, как полагается. в приведенном коде по крайней мере еще один href криво оформлен.

Comment: Github Pages в принципе не поддерживает Python, так что вы творите бессмыслицу

Comment: @andreymal , попробовать стоило... =(